# Making stage from array, hitTestObject help needed

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make my script so that it makes levels based on an array.
The blocks are placing fine but I have to make it that if you jump and fall down that is stops the player on collision.

I have tried some ways to make it but I can't figure it out, so I'm here to ask for help.

Variable list:

```
    var player1:MovieClip;
    var up:Boolean = false;
    var left:Boolean = false;
    var right:Boolean = false;
    var isWalking:Boolean = false;
    var isJumping:Boolean = false;
    var isOnFloor:Boolean = false;
    var lastPressed = "";
    var jumpSpeedLimit:int = 15;
    var jumpSpeed:Number = jumpSpeedLimit;
    var currentLevel:Number;
    var newBlock:MovieClip;
    var level1:Array
    var blockHolder:Sprite = new Sprite;
```

Jump script:

```
public function playerJumpRight():void {
        if (!isJumping) {
            isOnFloor = false;
            isJumping = true;
            var xVel:Number = 2;
            var yVel:Number = -jumpSpeedLimit;  //velocity = snelheid
            var yAcc:Number = 1;

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoop);
            function onLoop(e:Event):void {
                if (isJumping) {
                    player1.y += yVel;
                    yVel += yAcc;
                    if (player1.hitTestObject(newBlock)) {
                        isOnFloor = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

CreateLevel script:

```
        function createLevel() {
        addChild(blockHolder);
        level1 = new Array(
        0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
        );
        for (var i:int = 1; i < level1.length; i++) {
            if (level1[i] == 1) {
                newBlock = new MovieClip();
                newBlock.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
                newBlock.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
                newBlock.y = 400;
                newBlock.x = (i*newBlock.width+i)
                blockHolder.addChild(newBlock);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use a physics engine such as http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/ Unless you really want to make your own physics engine, that will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are checking only against last created block.  You will need to loop through all of the blocks to see if they overlap with the player. Also, for creating games, try some of the game engines already out there, like Flashpunk or Flixel, it's easier to work with them.